# How to check if another file is in the same directory of the current running application?

Tags: c#

I have 2 files, first is the current running application (file1.exe) and the second is just another file of any type (file2.*)

How can I check in the source code of file1.exe if the second file is in the same directory where the first file is executed?

I am familiar with File.Exists(path) so I think this boils down on finding out a method that will return the directory where the first file is ran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

That should do it

Comment: Thank you Killercam and @user1876228

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Here's a link to the MSDN docs for [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Or

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

The first of these methods is likely to be more efficent. But for jobs such as this who cares! :]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`File.Exists("file2.whatever");` Should work by default, as `Exists` will accept a relative path too.

The only time I have found this to be inaccurate is when you have set a different Working Directory to where you launched the app from.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [GetEntryAssembly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx):

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

This will return your *.exe even if called from another assembly

Comment: BEWARE: you are right _only if_ the assembly you want is the first executable that was executed by AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly.